# Using Android C++ library on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, java-native-interface

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK that it will use OpenCV.

This app is a migration from an Android app, and I will use all it C++ files on my iOS project.

On C++ files I have functions signatures like this one:

`myFunction(JNIEnv * jenv, jclass jobj, jint width, jint height,jintArray leftDetectionRectArray, jintArray rightDetectionRectArray )`

Can I use these C++ files without any changes on my iOS code? or do you I have to do some changes on them?

What do you recommend me?

Comment: Looks like you are using JNI, so there will have to be *some* changes before it will work under iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use those C/C++ files in you iOS code without modification.

The part using JNI may only be an interface to your real code (in pure C/C++), in which case you can remove it and either directly use the C/C++ code or create an objective-C interface.

The JNI functions are not and will not be defined on iOS as there is no Java Virtual Machine on iOS-based device (at least not in any official release).

Comment: I know that. I'm going to use only `.cpp` and `.hpp` files. Are you saying that I have to modify .cpp files to add new functions' signatures?

Comment: And you have to remove all refenrece to jni objects, types, and so on (or make a typedef for some tyes e.g. jint, as defined in jni.h)